# how to make Jenkins create a tunnel before polling from SVN

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I need to create a `tunnel` like the following before code can be checked out from SVN :

```
ssh -L 9898:some_server.com:9898 user@another_server.com
```

Now, I added `pre-scm-buildstep` plugin and wrote a script to open the tunnel before updating the repository as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198671/can-we-use-tunnelling-in-jenkins-before-connecting-to-the-svn-repository/13230638#13230638), but it doesn't work with polling. It only works if I ask Jenkins to '`Build now`'. In the setup where I have set it up to poll, its red saying that its `unable to access the repository url`, which can only happen if the tunnel was not created.

Is there any plugin such that I can execute a script `before it polls`, so that I can open the tunnel before it starts polling

Comment: Can't you keep the tunnel open outside of Jenkins?

Comment: I think I can write a shell script that checks when the tunnel breaks, and re-establish it. But I would rather integrate it inside my Jenkins job (do all the automation with Jenkins alone)

Comment: Well, you could wrap svn command, I think a simple bat would work, where you (re-)start tunnel before running the real svn command with given args...

Comment: But I don't want to run the bat manually.. how to make Jenkins run the script before polling.. ScriptTrigger plugin has been suggested for that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198671/can-we-use-tunnelling-in-jenkins-before-connecting-to-the-svn-repository/13230638#13230638

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ProxyCommand](http://www.statusq.org/archives/2008/07/03/1916/) in your ssh config to have ssh automatically create the tunnel for you. e.g.,

```
Host another_server.com
    ProxyCommand ssh some_server.com exec nc %h %p
```

With the above in ~jenkins/.ssh/config (or whatever user jenkins runs as), when it tries to ssh to `another_server.com` it will actually ssh to `some_server.com` and run `nc` to forward the ssh connection to the `another_server.com`.

Comment: Thanks. but I need to do local port forwarding also like I mentioned in the question

Comment: @Daud I've assumed the port forwarding was so you could connect to svn via ssh through the forwarded port. If not, please provide details of how you connect to svn once the port has been forwarded.